# jaxws client request header is not working in remote servers

Tags: java, jax-ws

WE have done the development of consuming the JAXWS service, when we call the service in the local server it is working. Means proper header and body of the request is created and getting the proper response for the same.

When we deploy the same code in the remote server (unix), the request is triggering without header. Please helps is something we are doing wrong here.

```
public ABCPortType initABCCheckStub(String sEndpointUrl) throws AxisFault, Exception{
                System.out.println( "endpointUrl : " + sEndpointUrl );

            URL baseUrl;
            baseUrl = com.def.xmlns.ABC.class.getResource("META-INF/wsdls/ABCCheck.wsdl");

            ABCCheck ABCCheckInfo = new ABCCheck(baseUrl,new QName("http://xmlns.ABC.com/", "Untitled"));
            ABCPortType abcPort = ABCCheckInfo.getSOAPEventSource();

            ((BindingProvider) abcPort).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,sEndpointUrl);


            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            List<Handler> handlerChain = new ArrayList<Handler>();
            handlerChain.add(new WSSecurityHeaderSOAPHandler());

            ((BindingProvider) abcPort).getBinding().setHandlerChain(handlerChain);

            System.out.println( "exiting initKAMCheckStub( )");
            return abcPort;
    }
```

**WebserviceSecurityHeader**

```
package com.abcd.webservice.handler;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;



public class WSSecurityHeaderSOAPHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {


private static final String SOAP_ELEMENT_FROM = "From";
private static final String SOAP_ELEMENT_ACTION = "Action";
private static final String SOAP_ELEMENT_MESSAGEHEADER = "MessageHeader";
private static final String NAMESPACE_SECURITY = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";
private static final String PREFIX_SECURITY = "env";


public WSSecurityHeaderSOAPHandler() {

}

public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext soapMessageContext) {

        System.out.println("Start -> handleMessage()");

    Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) soapMessageContext.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

    if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {

        try {
            SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapMessageContext.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();

            SOAPHeader header = soapEnvelope.getHeader();
            if (header == null) {
                header = soapEnvelope.addHeader();
            }

            SOAPElement soapElementSecurityHeader = header.addChildElement(SOAP_ELEMENT_MESSAGEHEADER, PREFIX_SECURITY,NAMESPACE_SECURITY);

            //From
            SOAPElement soapElementFrom = soapElementSecurityHeader.addChildElement(SOAP_ELEMENT_FROM, PREFIX_SECURITY);
            SOAPElement soapElementPartyID = soapElementFrom.addChildElement(SOAP_ELEMENT_PARTYID, PREFIX_SECURITY);
            soapElementPartyID.addTextNode("INTERSHOP");



            System.out.println("Exit -> handleMessage()");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error on wsSecurityHandler  ->"+e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public void close(MessageContext context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
    }
}
```